# Let $f\colon\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be a monotone function. Then $f$ is bounded on $\mathbb{R}$ if and only if $f\in BV(\mathbb{R})$

Tags: real-analysis, proof-explanation

First start writing the definition of $BV$ function on $\mathbb{R}$.

> A function $f\colon\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is said a bounded variation on $\mathbb{R}$ if it is in $BV([a,b])$ for all $-\infty<a<b<+\infty$ and results $$V(f):=\sup_{-\infty<a<b <+\infty} V_a^b(f)<\infty.$$

In my text there is write that a monotone function $f\colon \mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ is in $BV(\mathbb{R})$ if and only if it is bounded We have in fact that $$V(f)=|f(+\infty)-f(-\infty)|\tag1$$

> What does $(1)$ mean?

To explain $(1)$ I reason as follows: since $f$ is a monotone function we have that $$V_a^b(f)=|f(b)-f(a)|$$ and then $$V(f)=\sup_{-\infty<a<b<+\infty} V_a^b(f)=\sup_{-\infty<a<b<+\infty} |f(b)-f(a)|.$$

From this how do I get $(1)$?

**My attempt**

Let's see if I understood from the  Ted Shifrin's comment.

When $b\uparrow\infty$, we have that $V_a^b(f)\uparrow$, then

$$\lim_{b\uparrow \infty} V_a^b(f)=\lim_{b\uparrow\infty}|f(b)-f(a)|=|\lim_{b\uparrow\infty}f(b)-f(a)|$$ and when $a\downarrow -\infty$ then $V_a^b(f)\uparrow$ and then

$$\lim_{a\downarrow -\infty} |f(b)-f(a)|=|f(b)-\lim_{a\downarrow -\infty}f(a)|.$$ Therefore we have that

$$V(f)=\lim_{a\downarrow -\infty}\lim_{b\uparrow\infty}|f(b)-f(a)|=|\lim_{b\uparrow\infty}f(b)-\lim_{a\downarrow-\infty}f(a)|.$$

It's correct?

Comment: Since $f$ is monotonic, $V_a^b(f)$ increases as $b\uparrow\infty$ and as $a\downarrow -\infty$.

Comment: @TedShifrin I have correct now, sorry. Could you explain the details better? Thank you very much.

Comment: If $f$ is monotone, then it is either increasing or decreasing. If it is increasing, then $$\lim_{(a,b) \to (-\infty,\infty)} V_a^b(f) = \lim_{b \to \infty}f(b) - \lim_{a\to -\infty} f(a) = f(+\infty) - f(-\infty)$$ When $f$ is decreasing, $$\lim_{(a,b) \to (-\infty,\infty)} V_a^b(f) = \lim_{a \to -\infty}f(a) - \lim_{b\to \infty} f(b) = f(-\infty) - f(+\infty)$$In either case, the limit equals $|f(+\infty) - f(-\infty)|$.